# What is a "false positive" rejected promise? possiblyUnhandledRejection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

Im using the Bluebird promise library in node.

I have a section in my code that catches a rejected promise and does not re-throw it.

"unhandledRejection" is still triggered with that same promise afterwards - why is this when it has already been handled?

What is a "possiblyUnhandledRejection"?

http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/error-management-configuration.html

> However because it is possible to handle a rejected promise at any
>   time in the indeterminate future, **some programming patterns will
>   result in false positives**. Because such programming patterns are not
>   necessary and **can always be refactored to never cause false positives**,
>   we recommend doing that to keep debugging as easy as possible.

What are the "programming patterns" mentioned here?

Is this related to this pattern (one rejected promise is chained twice or more and one of them does not catch):
https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/695#issuecomment-155373565

Thanks

Comment: If you need help with your code, show us that section.

Comment: I'm not surprised you're having a problem with that section of Bluebird documentation. It's far from clear.

Answer (score 3):

The mentioned programming practices involve installing the error handler only after the error already occurred. For an example, take

```
var a = Promise.delay(Math.random()*1000)
        .then(function(){ throw new Error(); });
var b = Promise.delay(Math.random()*1000)
        .then(function() { return a; })
        .catch(function() { console.log("It's ok."); });
```

In about half the cases, `a`'s delay is shorter than `b`'s, and we'll get an `unhandledRejection` warning.

> Is this related to the pattern where one rejected promise is chained twice or more and one of them does not catch?

No, that's simply a bug. All branches need to have an error handler.

Comment: thanks, so what is `false positive` in your example? and do you know if there are plans to implement `delay` and `allSettled` methods in the native promises?

Comment: and is my understanding correct that when the callback `function() { return a; }` is executed, the `a` is in the `rejected` state? so this is sort of what happens `function() { return Promise.reject(valueAIsRejectedWith); }`

Comment: any comments to my questions above or should I create new question?

Comment: @Maximus Yes, that is what happens. When that callback is executed, the rejection is handled by the `catch`, but it might previously have been reported as an `unhandledRejection`. Which is false in this case. Regarding `delay` and `allSettled`, no and no.

Comment: @Maximus Yes. The only method currently being discussed is `finally`.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. I remember you said about half a year ago that it's too early to use native Promises as API is very limited, so as I understand the situation hasn't changed much for today?

Comment: @Maximus Sorry, I don't remember everything that I said months ago :-) Yes, there will always be libraries that offer a richer interface than native promises, but when to use which always depends on the particular case. The native API is enough for most things, especially when coupled with control flow from `async`/`await`.